# Papoulis 4th Ed. 2-16 - A box contains n identical balls numbered 1 through n. Suppose k balls are drawn in succession.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

I'm having trouble with the following problem:

> A box contains $n$ identical balls numbered $1$ through $n$. Suppose $k$ balls
> are drawn in succession.
>
> (a) What is the probability  that $m$ is the
> largest number drawn?
>
> (b) What is the probability that the largest
> number drawn is less than or equal to $m$?

The results are (according to the solutions manual), respectively:

> $$\frac{m-1 \choose k-1 }{n \choose k }$$
> $$\frac{m \choose k }{n \choose k }$$

My understanding of the problem is as follows:

There are $n$ balls in total, $k$ are drawn, so there are $k$ random numbers from $1$ to $n$. I'm asked to find if the greatest number between all the ones that were drawn ($k$), equals $m$ (for part a) and $\le m$ (for part b).

I get that the binomial coefficient in the denominator are all the different ways to arrange in a group of $k$ the $n$ balls. But I have no clue on how to find the numerator.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(a) The largest number drawn is $m$ precisely if $m$ is drawn, and all the other $k-1$ balls drawn are $\le m-1$. There are $\binom{m-1}{k-1}$ ways to choose $k-1$ balls from the balls numbered $1$ to $m-1$.

(b) The probability that the balls are all $\le m$ is simpler. There are $m$ such balls, and therefore $\binom{m}{k}$ ways to choose $k$ of them.

*Remark:* The answer to (b) can be used to find an alternate form of the answer to (a). The number of ways to have $m$ be largest can, by (b), be written as $\binom{m}{k}-\binom{m-1}{k}$.

Comment: I _kind of_ understood the parts for (a) and (b), but didn't really get your final remark, could you elaborate?

Comment: The probability the largest is equal to $m$ is the probability they are all $\le m$ minus the probability they are all $\le m-1$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. In some cases the easiest way to find $\Pr(X=m)$ is by using the strategy of the comment. That's why I mentioned it. For example, if we were sampling from the balls *with replacement*, the probability that the largest is $m$ would be $\frac{m^k}{n^k}-\frac{(m-1)^k}{n^k}$.

Comment: Thanks again. I definitely need a lot of practice with this kind of problem.

Answer (score 3):

(a) $m$ is the largest number drawn. So, one of the $k$ balls is $m$. The other $k-1$ balls can have any number which is less than $m$,i.e, any number from $1$ to $m-1$. Basically you are choosing $k-1$ from $m-1$

So, you get $$\frac{m-1 \choose k-1 }{n \choose k }$$

(b) The greatest number is less than or equal to $m$. So, you can pick any $k$ balls out of $m$

So, you get $$\frac{m \choose k }{n \choose k }$$